# How to revert the commits from git when CI build fails in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline for .NET Core application. Whenever we commit a change from local, it gets synced to the remote repository and then the CI/CD process in VSTS is triggered. If the build fails due to some reason (say test fails), shouldn't it revert the changes back from git repository? Please let me know if there is a way to do this

Comment: If you want to revert the commit back for this time, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~` to reset the branch back to the previous commit, and then you can use `git push -f` to force push to VSTS. For the long term, you can use pull request to verify if the changes can build successful before making changes to the branch (as Daniel said).

Comment: Marina thanks for the answer, how can we add this command to the end of the failed build and retrigger again>?

Answer (score 2):

No, it shouldn't do that automatically. Your process needs some revamping to support that workflow.

Use pull requests with a branch policy on your target branch for the merge. The branch policy can enforce a CI requirement.

You'll create a branch, develop in the branch, integrate changes to the *target* branch into your branch, *then* push your branch to the remote and open a PR. The PR will queue a build and fail the PR if your build fails. You can then make changes to correct the issue *on your branch* and repeat the process.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. But how about feature branches? Is there a way to prevent check-ins to feature branches when developer tries to commit bad code or code with failing tests :)

Comment: Put a branch policy on it.

Comment: he is not asking to do pull requests. PR can be automation nightmare

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin He asked for a method to prevent bad changes from getting merged into a branch. This is the exact use case for pull requests and branch policies.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin I'd love a more in depth explanation of what automation you're doing that is impeded by pull requests. I've worked with a lot of companies and I've never heard anyone say anything about pull requests causing problems with automation.

Comment: Pr is baby sitting the devs why use humans to do qa where we can automate via tests. Why make things more complicated focus on trunk based development.